# Laravel not debugging

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

This is my Laravel Routes File

```
Route::get('d', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

I have debug set to `true` but when I navigate to localhost:8000 instead of localhost:8000/d, I get a blank page instead of the not found http exception.But when I navigate to localhost:8000/d , everything works as usual .

Please tell me how to get debugging fixed.

Comment: No , no I want a stack trace when I hit the wrong route

Comment: You may have replaced the `/` path with `d`. And homepage should not throw `http not found exception` because Laravel is front controller pattern and front page is always found.

Comment: Then hit the wrong route like `/foo` it will not work and you will see the debug message.

Comment: you most probably dont have the .htaccess in place (public root)

Comment: @alou If `.htaccess` wasn't there then `/d` would not work either.

Comment: I hit foo and every other wrong route which gives me a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magically resolved somehow, Just reinstalled Laravel , this is my terminal log

```
[Mon Jun  9 19:13:27 2014] 127.0.0.1:48483 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:13:50 2014] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could not find resource 'views/layout.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/resources, /var/www/working/laravel-master/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/../Resources)' in /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php:10631
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(10513): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->getResource('views/layout.ht...')
#1 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(10361): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->handle(Object(RuntimeException))
#2 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(8837): Whoops\Run->handleException(Object(RuntimeException))
#3 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(8943): Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(RuntimeException))
#4 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(8895): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->displayException(Object(R in /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 10631
[Mon Jun  9 19:13:50 2014] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could not find resource 'views/layout.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/resources, /var/www/working/laravel-master/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/../Resources)' in /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php:10631
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(10513): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->getResource('views/layout.ht...')
#1 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(10361): Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#2 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(8837): Whoops\Run->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#3 /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(8943): Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#4 /home in /home/nsnihalsahu/code/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 10631
[Mon Jun  9 19:13:50 2014] 127.0.0.1:48485 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:13:50 2014] 127.0.0.1:48486 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:19:27 2014] 127.0.0.1:48610 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:19:27 2014] 127.0.0.1:48611 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:19:29 2014] 127.0.0.1:48615 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:19:29 2014] 127.0.0.1:48616 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:19:32 2014] 127.0.0.1:48618 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Mon Jun  9 19:19:32 2014] 127.0.0.1:48619 [200]: /favicon.ico
^C
```